# Poor performance when constructing neo4j db on remote server through bolt

Tags: azure, neo4j, neo4j-bolt

I'm constructing a neo4j db from various sources with a c# script runing on local and connecting to neo4j with the official bolt driver. When creating the db in localhost it takes around 3 minutes to create both nodes and relationships but when connecting to a server hosted on Azure, just creating the nodes takes one hour and half.

Some metrics :

- ~370k nodes
- local computer : i7 with 16g ram and ssd
- remote computer : Azure Debian VM [Standard_DS2](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-linux-sizes?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Flinux%2Ftoc.json#ds-series)
- currently sending 1000 queries per transactions
- I have indexes on all the node Ids
- Azure metrics :[image: Azure metrics]

I can understand that it won't be as fast as creating a db on localhost but can't find the reason for such a difference.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Its really classic creation queries like :

`MERGE (n:NodeArt {id:$id})
    ON CREATE SET n.nature = $nature, n.dateDebut = $dateDebut, n.dateFin = $dateFin`

I use the 'out of the box' config with heap size and page cache size dynamically calculated.

Comment: Can you share your queries and query plans? What are the settings for page-cache and heap for your Azure instance?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I edited my question to anwser yours :)